# create multiple named ranges with multiple selection

Tags: excel, vba

i just get one names range with this code, what's my fault?

any help, my language is so bad, sorry!

```
Sub Create_Names()

Worksheets("DATA").Activate

Dim rng As Range
With ActiveSheet
    Set rng = Range("J2:J10, J47:S67")
End With
rng.Select
With Selection

'Set rng = Selection

Dim i As Integer
Dim n As Long
Dim new_range As Range

Dim col_num As Integer
Dim first_Row As Long
Dim last_row As Long

For i = 1 To rng.Columns.Count
    For n = rng.Rows.Count To 1 Step -1
       col_num = rng.Columns(i).Column
       first_Row = rng.Rows(1).Row
       last_row = rng.Rows(n).Row

       If Cells(last_row, col_num).Value <> "" Then
           Set new_range = Range(Cells(first_Row, col_num), Cells(last_row, col_num))
           new_range.CreateNames Top:=True
           Exit For
      End If
    Next n
Next i
End With
End Sub
```

i have a big data, and i want to create names range once to make it simple.. help me please..

i change my code and its work like i want..

```
for each rng in Application.Selection.Areas

'i run the code here


next rng
```

IS THERE LIMIT FOR CREATENAMES?

I GET ERROR WHEN I PUT

```
Set rng = Range("J2:J10, J47:S67,V47:BI77,BL1:BL21,CB35:CU64,CB120:FW170,CX20:MM35,CX51:EU61")
```

[My data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/COYMH.png)

[my name range](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TQcmB.png)

Comment: Please explain with an example what you're trying to achieve

Comment: for example i want  to make name for range A9:A10 and B9:B10 once,

Comment: Where do you define the ranges and the names? in cells of a specific sheet?

Comment: sorry my bro, my english so bad i from indonesia, i make my top row of selection become names..

Comment: Please [edit] your question and paste a screenshot of some sample data and then explain the expected results

Comment: check it bro, i finish edit my question

Comment: i want to add my all table to be names range,

Comment: How do you define the ranges' names?

Comment: @RicardoDiaz - Read [this tutorial](https://powerspreadsheets.com/vba-create-named-range/) on creating named ranges in vba. Your code does create any named ranges.

Comment: can you fix my code, pliss.. i have use my all night to fix it..

Comment: @Irfan - see my tutorial for creating named ranges via code.

Comment: sorry @RicardoDiaz. Wrong @!

Comment: @ScottHoltzman no worries I know. Just kidding.